# Image not found in resources folder

Tags: c#, image

I have one project which has 10 buttons with assigned images. 
I have set image property in apperance. At that time I have a resource folder in which images were stored. But after a long time I lost that folder. I can't find any images in this project. Or I have not found the resources folder. I find also using search tool in that folder.

Can anyone tell me from where I got that image which displayed on button. I also checked designer code also. In it contains paths like these:

```
// 
// CmdShpSE
// 
appearance161.BackGradientAlignment = Infragistics.Win.GradientAlignment.Client;
appearance161.BackGradientStyle = Infragistics.Win.GradientStyle.Circular;
appearance161.FontData.BoldAsString = "False";
appearance161.FontData.Name = "Tahoma";
appearance161.FontData.SizeInPoints = 11F;
appearance161.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
appearance161.Image = ((object)(resources.GetObject("appearance161.Image")));
appearance161.ImageHAlign = Infragistics.Win.HAlign.Center;
appearance161.ImageVAlign = Infragistics.Win.VAlign.Top;
```

Help please. I need these images.

Comment: try cut it via snipping tool and then google that image, if you are just looking for the image itself.

Comment: It should be in the resx file of your form (or whatever control you've got there). You double click it in Visual Studio, and it should be there under the name of "appearance161.Image". You can than save it to file system again.

Comment: i know very well about snipping tools but it's descress resolution. i want only that image which in saved in control...

Comment: i got that file code. thanks Luaan..

it's in particular form. but it's in byte..
have any idea about to convert that byte code to image. ?